# WP8: How to change the fonts size and family of the contents displayed in webBrowser?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I was developing windows phone 8 app. I was displaying local html files in my app using `<phone:webBrowser>` class. I have changed app's fonts totally. But, I can't change the font style (size and family) for the content displayed in the webBrowser. How to change the fonts style for those content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option that you can go for is with a CSS style sheet. You can embed the style inside the html document and then pass that html file in to web browser. It will work

Comment: are you sure ? let me check anyway,

Comment: Yes i am sure.. I tired something similar previously. In my static FAQ Page

Comment: its not working for changing font-family ? i need to use ttf fonts ?

Comment: Try add the ttf fonts locally and then refer that from your html page.

Comment: not works;

`<style>
  @font-face
  {
  font-family: myFont;
  src: url('fonts/my-font.ttf');
  }
  body
  {
  font-family: myFont;
  }
</style>`

Comment: try something like this,   <body style="background:#000000; color:#ffffff;font-family: Segoe UI">

Comment: Ok, Let me try this and i will build a sample for you.. once i am free.